# plot not showing up when trying to plot pandas table

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have some data in CSV file and want to plot it but the grapgh not showing up

this is a screenshot showing data table and code [image]

this is the CSV file http://www.mediafire.com/file/2gtbxm5adom7m4j/pop.csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your jupyter notebook configuration, it may not show plots by default. Either add this magic command to a cell in your notebook:

`%matplotlib inline`

or add a call to `plt.show()` after each plot call.